# Mixing by the cat map : proof?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mixing

Let $f : \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ be the "cat map" defined by $f(x,y)=(2x+y \mod 1,x+y\mod 1)$.

> How can I prove that $f$ is exponentially mixing on $\mathbb{T}^2$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure? That is, there exists $\lambda <1$ and $C>1$ such that for all measurable sets $A, B$, $\left\vert\,\,|f^{-n}(A)\cap B|-|A||B|\,\,\right\vert \leqslant C \lambda^n$.

When one deals with ergodicity there are some handy characterizations for which one can use that $f$ acts like the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$. Is there a similar characterization for the notion of strong mixing?

Thanks.

Comment: I would try using the observation that $|f^{-n}(A) \cap B| = \int_{\mathbb{T}^{2}} (\chi_{A} \circ f^{n}) \chi_{B} \, dx$ and try Parseval's Theorem.  (You should be able to say something about the Fourier coefficients of $\chi_{A} \circ f^{n}$ using the matrix representation of $f^{n}$.)

Comment: There are nine $|$ in your inequality. I am unsure how to parse them. Could you please either remove the extra vertical line, or add the missing line? And can you use `\|` = $\|$ instead of `||` if you mean a norm? Perhaps some parentheses might be helpful too.

Comment: @PeterMorfe thanks you, I will try.